# converting a pointer to a non pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

What exactly happens when you convert a pointer to a non-pointer type?
For example:

```
int i = 7;
int *y = &i;

printf("%x %d %x", y, (int)y,7);
```

The result when compiled and run is:

```
29ff00 2752256 7
```

But what actually resulted - where did the number come from? Is it a random number or something related to what the pointer held?

Does it have a mathematical value such as the address or is the value of the pointer converted by some standard?

Comment: Is this a C or a C++ question?

Comment: Notice that your code contains *undefined behaviour:* You pass an argument of pointer type for the `%x` formatting specifier to `printf` whereas you should actually pass an argument of type `int`. Use `%p` to print pointers.

Comment: In addition of twentylemon answer note that it is a UB. You can probably easily see it on 64-bit system, as you would give a 64-bit argument while variadic function read only 32-bits - with arguments on stack it will cause misalignment and garbage values (though exact behaviour depends on compiler/ABI/phase of moon...). It's better to use `%p` to avoid dealing with UB, trucation and other fun staff - for sure it is not guaranteed to be the same as casting as `NULL` must be `0` but is allowed to have different bit representation.

Answer (score 4):

2752256 is the decimal value of the memory address 29ff00. You'd get a similar result with

```
printf("%x %d", y, y);
```